# How to create 2 kinds of ToC chapter, one for abstract and one for the other chapters

Tags: chapters, indexing

I have an example here.
I want to delete the index of chapter 1, so that it begins with the index of section.[image]

But I want to keep the index of other chapters.
Can anyone help me? Thank you.

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents{}
\chapter{Editing compile}
\section{First Compile}
\subsection{Output formats}
\chapter{Document Structure}
\section{Reserved Characters}
\section{Reserved Characters abc}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

The following manipulation seems to work for what you want:

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}% Section numbers should not include \thechapter
\chapter*{Editing compile}% Set unnumbered \chapter
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect\numberline{}Editing compile}% Put chapter in ToC (as if it's numbered)
\stepcounter{chapter}% Step regular chapter counter
\section{First Compile}
\subsection{Output formats}

\renewcommand{\thesection}{\thechapter.\arabic{section}}% Restore default (recursive) section numbering
\chapter{Document Structure}
\section{Reserved Characters}
\section{Reserved Characters abc}

\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you so much. It works